# anchor tag not working when it has span inside

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, anchor

Why I can not have this as an achor tag?

Why the below code is not working.

I have `p` which has `a`, `a` has `span` and `a` closes after `span`

Here's the code. What's wrong?

```
      <p class="paraClass"> 
        <a>
         <span id="cartitems">
         <%= pluralize(@size, 'item') %>     
         </span>  
        </a>
      </p>
```

Please help

Comment: What you mean by Anchor tag not workin ? is there NO clickable link generated ?

Comment: it is not clickable, although hover property works

Comment: can you set the HREF property of anchor tag and check ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An A-Tag needs to have a href - else its just a anchor.

A Good way is to use a helper of rails called `link_to`
You can use it in two ways, just pass content-string and url, or pass url and a block. If you pass a block, the return of the block will be used as the display of the a-tag.

`link_to "content", "url", {options}`

`link_to "url", {options} do 
   block
end`

Unless you're just using some string as the display-text, i always recommend you to use the block-style. It is easier for you to edit something inside of that block and of course its easier to read and understand.

In your case it would be:

```
<p class="paraClass"> 
    <%= link_to "#", onclick: "return false;" do %>
      <span id"cartitems">
         %= pluralize(@size, 'item') %>    
      </span>
    <%- end %>
</p>
```

Maybe you want to switch to **haml** which helps you to write html with ease. In Haml the same code looks sweet within 2 lines of code:

```
=link_to "#" do
  %span#cartitems=pluralize @size, "item"
```

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE:** [ as per comment ]

Its simple. Only add the **href tag** like below code:

```
<p class="paraClass"> 
    <a>
     <span id="cartitems">
     <%= pluralize(@size, 'item') %>     
     </span>  
    </a>
  </p>

<!-- here simply changing the color -->
<style>
 a { cursor: pointer; }
 a:hover{ color: #ff9900; }
</style>
```

Comment: I don't want to redirect the page to anywhere. I am toggling something on the click to it. But I want to have the hover effect on anchor

Comment: @Suraj if you want only **hover** effect then use css property on **a tag**. See update answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
<%= link_to content_tag(:span, pluralize(@size, 'item') ), '#' %>
```

use link to tag with content_for... so that it will show u how u want